# Gets an error of 500, in the function I want to put in the firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, axios

Hello everyone I am new here on the site, I joined just a few days ago.

I have a problem that I do not understand why I have it.
I have a server side function I built, I call it axios.
I happen to her on the client side.

These are the steps of calling a function:

Client side calling:

```
export const getRealtimeConversations = (user) => (dispatch) => {

    //testing
    user = { uid_1: user.handle, uid_2: chat.handle };

    axios.get('/realtimeConversations', 
    {
        params: {
            user: JSON.stringify(user)
        }
      }
    )
        .then((res) => {
            dispatch({
                type: userConstants.GET_REALTIME_MESSAGES,
                payload: res.data
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))

}
```

The axios:

```
app.get('/realtimeConversations', FBAuth, getRealtimeConversations);
```

The function itself on the server side:

```
exports.getRealtimeConversations = (req, res) => {

    if (req.query.user) {
        user = JSON.parse(req.query.user);
      }

    db.collection('conversations')
        .where('user_uid_1', 'in', [user.uid_1, user.uid_2])
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {

            const conversations = [];

            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

                if (
                    (doc.data().user_uid_1 == user.uid_1 && doc.data().user_uid_2 == user.uid_2)
                    ||
                    (doc.data().user_uid_1 == user.uid_2 && doc.data().user_uid_2 == user.uid_1)
                ) {
                    conversations.push(doc.data())
                }

            });
            console.log(conversations);
            return res.json(conversations);
        })
}
```

I get an error message 500, I tried to run the function through the postman but I get an error 500.

this is how i call it in postman:

[image]

I'm pretty sure there's something very small here that's ruining my function. Maybe I happen to function through get in axios, maybe I do not get the parameters properly. But I do not know how to test it, because the function does not work

the error that i got in the client side:

```
xhr.js:177 GET https://europe-west1-socialife-c468b.cloudfunctions.net/api/realtimeConversations 500
```

the error that i got in the back side:

```
eferenceError: user is not defined
    at exports.getRealtimeConversations (/workspace/handlers/chat.js:40:37)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
```

Comment: Can you add the error message as well?

Comment: Try req.params.user instead of req.query.user

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the URL generated by postman, you see that there isn’t any query string parameter named `user`, but two parameters `uid1` and `uid2`.

You need to adapt your Cloud Function to get the values of these two parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried to change it, I'm currently getting a 404 error inside the postman. It does not run me the function at all, it does not find my request in axios

Comment: please update your question with the adapted code and the new errors corresponding to this new code.